# Filter ArrayList that has similar data

Tags: java, collections, guava

I have the following classes:

```
public class School{
List<ClassRoom> classRooms;
}

public class ClassRoom{
List<Student> students;
}

public class Student{
String name;
long typeId;
}
```

I need to get the whole students within the given class roomS that has typeID=123

Expected result:

List  filteredStudent=classRoomList.filterByStudentTypeID(typeIdToSearchFor)

I don't need to write some dirty code and loops.

I need to take advantage of existing libraries.
I found out Google Guava.

I found out a method at guava that searches by the the whole reference ... instead I need to search using the attribute, typeId

```
Collection<Student> filtered =Collections2.filter(students, Predicates.equalTo(s1));
```

Any ideas!

Comment: `I don't need to write some dirty code and loops`... wow. Maybe you need to dedícate yourself to a different discipline. Have you thought about phone sanitation?

Comment: Write your own `Predicate` implementation and use that in the call to `filter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Guava, you can use a custom predicate:

```
final long typeIdToSearchFor = ...;
Collection<Student> filtered = Collections2.filter(students,
    new Predicate<Student>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Student s) {
            return s.typeId == typeIdToSearchFor;
        }
    }
);
```

Note that `typeIdToSearchFor` must be `final` in the scope of the call to `filter` because it is being referenced by the (anonymous) `Predicate` subclass.

Comment: Thanks Ted Hopp for our assistance.

Comment: That said, its worth looking at this side by side with the "dirty" loops and comparing which is more readable.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - Amen. Of course, if OP were to find some sort of reusable `Predicate` implementation useful, that might weigh in favor of this approach. For a one-off requirement, though, I'd go with a loop.